# What exactly is "staging" and how does it fix DLL problems?

Tags: wine

I am trying to install World of Warcraft under wine. I keep seeing an error about a missing dbghelp.dll and the only advice I can find makes oblique references to something called "3.3 staging". As far as I can tell it is some fork or flavour of wine or something.

What exactly is "staging" and how does it fix my DLL problems?

Comment: https://wine-staging.com/

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/956209/difference-between-wine-staging-stable-devel-development